# How to check version is greater than some base value?

Tags: mysql

When calling MySQL `SELECT @@VERSION;` or `SELECT VERSION();`, I get for instance `'5.7.11-log'`. Is there a "well-known" way to check if the version is greater (or smaller) than some *major.minor.patch* version? If not a well-known way, is there a way without using a temporary table or a user-defined function (there probably is, but for a reason or another currently eludes me)? I would use this to check if there's support for [JSON type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) type that was introduced in version *5.7.8*.

Upon researching this more, it appears this is a bit tougher nut for my skills to crack. For instance, I could write something like

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(@@VERSION, '.', 1) AS major, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@@VERSION,'.', 2), '.', -1) AS minor, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@@VERSION,'.', -2), '.', -1) AS patch;
```

but that isn't entirely satisfactory (e.g. see -log) and it doesn't directly check the existence of the feature.

I cross-posted this to DBA overflow [How to check if feature (JSON) exists, and/or version](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161266/how-to-check-if-feature-json-exists-and-or-version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll cross reference the [answer by Rick here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/161272/29570). Specifically, there is special comments syntax in MySQL in which MySQL interprets a block of code either as effective MySQL SQL or as just a plain comments section. Here's a link to the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html and a few notable examples:

`SELECT /*!JSON_TYPE*/('["a", "b", 1]');`

and

`/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use if condition with version

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.14    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select if(VERSION() > '5.7.14' ,1,0);
+-------------------------------+
| if(VERSION() > '5.7.14' ,1,0) |
+-------------------------------+
|                             0 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select if(VERSION() > '5.7.13' ,1,0);
+-------------------------------+
| if(VERSION() > '5.7.13' ,1,0) |
+-------------------------------+
|                             1 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Hmm, it looks like `if('5.10.8' > '5.7.8', 1, 0) AS Version;` would be one counter example, where the expression should evaluate to true and choose `1`. Instead, `0` is chosen.